# Creating a shortcut with two files names one being variable?

Tags: inno-setup, shortcut

I want to create a shortcut that calls two files, first, it calls Excel.exe, then it calls my add-in.

I tested it doing the following:

```
Target:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\EXCEL.EXE" "C:\MyAddin.xll"
```

And it works fine. Now I want to implement it in inno-setup.

I have to get the Excel.exe location via some automation in inno-setup, which I store in a global variable.

This is what I've tried:

```
Name: {commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}; Filename: ExcelExecutablePath; 
Parameters: {app}\{#MyAppExeName}; Tasks: desktopicon; 
Flags: CreateOnlyIfFileExists; IconFilename: {app}\Icons\TimeCard64.ico;
```

I've tried other things too, but I'm at a bit of a loss on this one.

Thanks in advance. Let me know if I should be more clear on something!

Comment: Make sure you aren't actually installing your Addin into `c:\`. It should go into `{pf}\youraddin\` or similar.

Comment: @Deanna, Yeah, that was more just for example purposes, keeping it simple. Thanks for the advice though. I actually have it in {app}\myaddin.xll. Of course, after installing it I'm having other problems that I have yet to figure out :\ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the location of 'excel', you can query the 'App Paths' registry key if it includes 'excel.exe' in a function in code section. Example:

```
 
[Icons]
Name: "{commondesktop}\My Excel File"; Filename: "{code:GetExcelPath}"; Parameters: """C:\MyAddin.xll"""

..

[Code]
function GetExcelPath(dummy: string): string;
begin
  RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\excel.exe', '', Result);
  if Result = '' then
    Result := 'excel.exe';
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was great. I didn't see that registry address in my XP OS. So I just got the excel application and and did application.path to get the path. Also, I wouldn't have know that I needed to throw in the dummy variable, I did it without it first and was wondering why it wasn't compiling, wo and behold, I needed the dummy variable in my function!

Comment: @Jon - You're welcome! You can read about the necessary string parameter [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants).